# I can't split field in CrystalReports

Tags: vb.net

How to split the field Order_cos that contains "20225130012" to get just "0012" without "2022513" in CrystalReports?

I use this code `mid({Order_cos },9)` but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your code:

```vb
Dim Order_cos = "20225130012"
Mid({Order_cos}, 9)
```

The [Mid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.mid?view=net-6.0) function

*Returns a string that contains all the characters starting from a specified position in a string.

**Start**

Int32

Required. Integer expression. Starting position of the characters to return. If Start is greater than the number of characters in str, the Mid function returns a zero-length string (""). **Start is one-based**.*

So starting at the 9th character in the string, and taking the remaining characters, you get `012`

You can change the 9 to 8 to start at the character before it. I'd be surprised if you didn't try this so I guess there may be an issue in creating an array from your string when you pass it as `{Order_cos}` - why do this?  I don't even know if that compiles under all conditions, but it looks odd. Just pass the string.

```vb
Mid(Order_cos, 8)
```

Mid is a bit outdated, and you should look at newer functions in .NET (Mid is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace and c# users won't even see it by default). Try [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0). The index is zero-based which should jive with the rest of your .NET code.

```
Order_cos.SubString(7)
```

If you just want the last 4 characters, you could also do this

```vb
Order_cos.SubString(Order_cos.Length - 4)
```

Comment: where write this code in crystalreport ?

Comment: Wherever you put the vb.net code you provided.

Comment: but i want split in report in crysatreport not in vbcode

Comment: The only tag on your question is `vb.net`. I answered in vb.net